# Get process ID by part of its process name at Sigar

Tags: vmware, java, sigar

I'm using [Sigar library](https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) to get the process ID and monitor it.

I have a process which can change of name depending on the version of the application which runs that process. 
For example:

- myProcess64.exe
- myProcess65.exe

Is there a way using Sigar to get the process Id by specifing something like `myProcess%` ?

Right now I'm using this:

```
ProcessFinder find = new ProcessFinder(this.sigar);
long[] pids = find.find("Exe.Name.ct=" + this.processName);
```

I've been trying to use regular expresions by using the [PTQL (Process Table Query Language) syntax](https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/PTQL) without success:

```
//getting the process with name "Photoshop.exe" (not working currently)
long[] pids = find.find("Exe.Name.re=^Photo(.)*.exe$);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Exe.Name` returns the path to the running process, not just the name of the process.

Therefore your regular expression should look like this:

```
long[] pids = this.find.find("Exe.Name.re=^.*\\\\Photo(.)*.exe$");
```